# selectively run perl script on all **.dat files containing text "some_attr" in directory and sub directories

Tags: perl, awk, sed, scripting, grep

I want to run a perl script over all **.dat**  files containing text ***"some_attr"*** in the specified directory and its sub directories. How can I do that?
I can list all **.dat files containing** "some_attr" **using '***grep -nri some_attr  * ./'***
and run perl script manually over greped files,but I want to automate this  using perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a Bash shell, you can use a simple for loop combined with grep:

```
for file in `grep -lr some_attr | uniq`
do
   perl script_name.pl $file
done
```

Comment: i tried that but some files have multiple occurrences of some_attr and it runs multiple times

Comment: you can pipe the result of grep to `uniq` to get filenames only a single time.

Comment: -l is defined to only print a file's name one time, so either you have a broken grep or something else is going wrong.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen  On my system the man page includes this excerpt:  -l, --files-with-matches
              Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop on the first match.  (-l is specified by POSIX.)
... The 'stop scanning on first match' is what says it will only print a file's name one time.  if you I use -rn for each occurrence, with line number, and -rl for the just the file names.  As I said before, it could be your implementation of grep.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) or [`File::Find::Rule`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aRule):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use File::Find::Rule;

# find all the .dat files in .
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                            ->name( '*.dat' )
                            ->in( '.' );

for my ($file) {
    my $data = do {
        open my $fh, '<', $file;
        local $/;
        <$fh>;
    };

    next if $data !~ /some_attr/;

    print $file, "\n";
}
```

Comment: so do I have to replace print $file, "\n"; with my perl script.   e.g. perl -i_ myscript.pl $file

Comment: you COULD do that.  Or you can use this type of logic to edit your perl script.  I don't know if this is a one time operation, or if you want your perl script to permanently have this functionality.